# Shake a login form on error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have successfully built a login form using ajax and want to add a shake effect to the form when the user enters incorrect details. I have the function in place that will fire but just need to build the jquery effect **(note I know of jquery UI but don't want to use it! I don't want to use ANY plugins for this)**

So far I have:

```
function shakeForm() {

    var p = new Array(15, 30, 15, 0, -15, -30, -15, 0);
    p = p.concat(p.concat(p));


    $('form').css('left',p);

}
```

From what I understand I need to loop the array of values but how do I do that? Note that the element form has a position of relative already. So it's just a case of running those values as the left value in a random sequence?

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Why bother? 
Animations are queued.
More - instead a `left` attribute you can use `margin-left` what prevents to adding `position` attribute :)

```
function shakeForm() {
   var l = 20;  

   for( var i = 0; i <= 10; i++ ) {   
     $( 'form' ).animate( { 
         'margin-left': '+=' + ( l = -l ) + 'px',
         'margin-right': '-=' + l + 'px'
      }, 50);  
   }
}
```

Comment: Future readers: In case you missed it in the OP, Note that the element's position must be `relative`, so it may be necessary to modify chain to: `$( "form" ).css('postion','relative').animate( { 'margin-left': "+=" + ( l = -l ) + 'px' }, 50);`

Comment: Position in this case doesn't matter at all - margin it's always relative to  element itself. Btw it isn't efficient and doesn't make sense to set position(or any other constant parameter like that anyway) in loop.

Comment: QUESTION, how do you implement this beautiful code correctly, if I use onclick attribute to call function the form shakes regardless whether login info is correct or not

Comment: You need to create some validation logic first and run the animation when validation failed. Something like `if(!validate()) { shakeForm(); }`.
Basically `shakeForm` could be called `shakeInput` or just `shakeElement` then pass an reference to element `shakeElement(this)` if we're talking about onClick handler.

Answer (score 5):

Its better to use CSS to this instead of JS. CSS uses less resources(is faster) and its simpler. 
You can find good (and 'ready to use') examples here: https://daneden.me/animate/

Answer (score 4):

I have made a plugin for this .. check it http://static.mbiosinformatica.com.br/jQuery/

Is it working in IE ( 7 , 8 , 9 ) , Chrome and Firefox.

And, you can apply a callback function, to show error message .. or anything else.

```
$('#div').shake({
      positions : { 'L' : 50 , 'R' : 50 } , // shake only left and right (U,L,R,D)
      rotate : false , // rotate div on shake .. true/false
      parent : false  // shake parent div .. true/false
}, function(){ /* do something */ });
```

In the positions, you can send array too, just: `positions: [ [ 'L', 50  ... ] ]`
This value '**50**' its the shake distance from original position ..

---

To change timeout ( delay ) and effect duration, you have to set `timeout: [you timeout .. / delay ]` and the effect times .. `interval: ...`

Comment: This is a really nice plugin! But I recommend to make the duration of the effect customizeable too, in this example.

Comment: Thanks .. i improving it .. if you have a idea, contact me ! `andreykvital@gmail.com` ..

Comment: @Armin, edited .. just you can configure it with `timeout: 500, interval: 1 .. ` ;)

Comment: @AndreyKnupp read the OP: **`I don't want to use ANY plugins for this`**

Comment: Yes ... but him can get the idea of the plugin and do something like.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who are stubborn (like me) and hate libraries...

```
var e = document.getElementById('dividname');
e.style.marginLeft='8px';
setTimeout(function(){e.style.marginLeft='0px';},100);
setTimeout(function(){e.style.marginLeft='8px';},200);
setTimeout(function(){e.style.marginLeft='0px';},300);
```

then in your css:

```
.shakeClass{
   transition: margin 100ms;
}
```

Comment: this is excellent. Why use craps like JQ that mutilates way of thinking. Works wonderful even without CSS. Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

mmm why use native js if jquery animate() is available... you try recurring like this:

```
var p = new Array(15, 30, 15, 0, -15, -30, -15, 0);

function shakeForm(index) {
    if(typeof index === "undefined") index = 0;
    if(typeof p[index] === "undefined") return false;
    $("form").animate({
        "left": p[index]
    }, function() {
        shakeForm(index + 1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

loop throw the array using `jQuery.each`: http://jsfiddle.net/N8F7Z/1/

```
function shakeForm() {
    var p = "15 30 15 0 -15 -30 -15 0".split(" ");
    $.each(p, function(key, value) {
        var delay = 100;
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("form").css("left", value + "px");
        }, delay*key);
    });
}
```

A simple way to make an array is splitting a string with every space:

```
var p = "15 30 15 0 -15 -30 -15 0".split(" ");
```

The delay between each step:

```
var delay = 100;
```

Using `setTimeout(function() {...}, theTimeBeforeFiring )`

```
theTimeBeforeFiring = delay * key
```

key is the key the value has in the array:

```
key = 0, 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: hehe nice solution, but why use a string and **not** an array?

Comment: i don't know. Just faster to write. :)

Answer (score 0):

jquery animations are queued by default, so you just need to call `animate` for each element of the array:

```
function shakeForm() {
    var p = [15, 30, 15, 0, -15, -30, -15, 0];
    var x = $('form').offset().left;
    var speed = 40;
    $.each(p, function() {
        $('form').animate({'left': x + this}, speed);
    });
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3qdFL/

Answer (score 0):

The examples above change the original position of the element.

```
function shakeForm() {
    var margin = 15;
    var speed = 50;
    var times = 5;
    for( var i = 0; i < times; i++ ){  
        $( "form" ).animate( { 'margin-left': "+=" + ( margin = -margin ) + 'px' }, speed); 
        $( "form" ).animate( { 'margin-right': "+=" + ( margin = -margin ) + 'px' }, speed); 
        $( "form" ).animate( { 'margin-right': "+=" + ( margin = -margin ) + 'px' }, speed);
        $( "form" ).animate( { 'margin-left': "+=" + ( margin = -margin ) + 'px' }, speed);
    }
}
```

demo here http://jsfiddle.net/UW6tN/1/

Answer (score 0):

why not use css3 animations? less over head in my opinion. There so many plugins that exist because so many reinvent the wheel... I searched for the same thing and got 20 results of forums, and jquery plugins(yet another script to add)..but I found this and it works of coarse.

not my answer but it pure css3!

[CSS animation similar to Mac OS X 10.8 invalid password "shake"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726000/css-animation-similar-to-mac-os-x-10-8-invalid-password-shake)