# CSS animation similar to Mac OS X 10.8 invalid password "shake"?

Tags: html, macos, css, user-interface, css-animations

On the Mac OS X 10.8 "password" screen, if you enter an invalid password, it will "shake" back and forth (a.k.a. left and right).  I am trying to achieve an similar effect for an HTML password input field using CSS animations.

I created a ["Password Shake" jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hakanson/MWgnf/) that seems to emulate this behavior.  However, it doesn't seem quite right.  I'm not sure the explicit keyframes and the `linear` timing function are the right approach.  This is my first attempt at a CSS animation, and I'm looking for feedback on the right way to achieve this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <input type="password" id="demo-password" placeholder="password" autofocus />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#demo-password').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var $input = $(this);
    var val = $.trim($input.val());
    $input.removeClass("invalid");

    if (e.which !== 13 || !val) {
        return;
    }

    if (val != "password") {
        $input.select();   
        $input.addClass("invalid");
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#demo-password.invalid {
    outline-color: red;
    /* also need animation and -moz-animation */
    -webkit-animation: shake .6s linear;
}
/* also need keyframes and -moz-keyframes */
 @-webkit-keyframes shake {
    0% {
        left:-10px;
    }
    16% {
        left:9px;
    }
    33% {
        left:-6px;
    }
    50% {
        left:5px;
    }
    66% {
        left:-2px;
    }
    83% {
        left:1px;
    }
    100% {
        left: 0px;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

I did find [Animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/) which has a shake animation.  I've included the (non browser prefixed) CSS below.  Instead of setting `left` is does a `transform: translateX()`, which likely has a better chance for hardware acceleration.

```
.animated {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes shake {
    0%, 100% {transform: translateX(0);}
    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {transform: translateX(-10px);}
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {transform: translateX(10px);}
}

.shake {
    animation-name: shake;
}
```

Comment: i don't know if it is  exactly right but it looks good.

Comment: [JQuery UI offers](http://jqueryui.com/effect/) what you are looking for. You may benefit from looking at their code.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I used my iPad camera to record the Mac pasword screen.  It looks like it shakes 3 times each direction, with the first 2 going the full distance and the last 1 time a lesser distance.

```
#demo-password.invalid {
    outline-color: red;
    /* also need animation and -moz-animation */
    -webkit-animation: shake .5s linear;
}
/* also need keyframes and -moz-keyframes */
 @-webkit-keyframes shake {
    8%, 41% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
    }
    25%, 58% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-5px);
    }
    92% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(5px);
    }
    0%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm man, thank you. I simply adjusted the pixel transitions to 7px and 4px and speeded it up 100ms to fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd give [jRumble](http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/#demos) a shot too, it has a very large set of shakes and they can be combined to make all sorts of crazy stuff happen. Some fun examples:

- [Shake based on a percentage](http://bit.ly/JgSyI6)
- [Time based shake](http://bit.ly/ZzC7LG)

Answer (score 0):

I thought the original poster's shake animation looked the most natural and fluid compared to all that were posted here.  So here it is using `transform` instead of positionals:

```
0% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
}
16% {
    transform: translateX(9px);
}
33% {
    transform: translateX(-6px);
}
50% {
    transform: translateX(5px);
}
66% {
    transform: translateX(-2px);
}
83% {
    transform: translateX(1px);
}
100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```