# Add a shake effect on a div when inputs are not valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to make this divs shakes when the inputs are not valids (or they don't have been filled): http://jsfiddle.net/jalxob/ahQLC/13/

I tried to do it by myself using:

```
    .effect('shake');
```

Can someone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645361/shake-a-login-form-on-error

Some good responses here about it...

Comment: Check this fiddle.  [http://jsfiddle.net/f9wRU/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/f9wRU/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this wherever you want it to be invoked:

```
<div id="inputbox"></div>


$( document ).click(function() {
  $("#inputbox").effect( "shake" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include jQuery UI. In JSFiddle you need to select `JQuery UI` on the option list under Frameworks & Extensions. Assuming this is in a project, you'll need to include the [jQuery UI library](http://jqueryui.com/).

Comment: Oh I see. I am new with coding. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

what about [animate.css](https://daneden.me/animate/). You just need `animate.css`

```
<button id="shakebtn">shake</button>

<div id="shakediv">
this is shake test. shake demo on div. please click shake button.
</div>
<script>
$('#shakebtn').click(function(){
    $('#shakediv').removeClass().addClass('animated shake')
    .one('webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
   });
});
</script>
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f9wRU/5/)

Comment: Nice non-jquery-ui solution, css file is now 404 however

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Include Jquery UI JS and Use `shake()` function in your files

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ahQLC/15/)